# repeat a method or funcion 1 or more times if it throwed an exception

Tags: c#, .net, function, exception, methods

I have this code snippet (led panel driver):

```
string strIP = ip1; //.Replace(',','.');
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIP);
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* pIP = bytes)
    {
        int ddd = Huidu_InitDll(nSreenID, 2, pIP, strIP.Length + 1);
        if (ddd != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");
            sendmail(Convert.ToString(Huidu_GetLastError()));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Many times it throws the error (and the email) because of the high ping I guess. How to solve that e.g. try it 3 times then send the error report?

Comment: use some kind of loop? Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: where exactly does it throw the error?

Comment: the problem is that the "ddd" variable sometimes 0 then shows the error and the code breaks. I want to give the funciton two more tries before it breaks. Shall I simple put it in a loop with different intervals or two more if/else statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int retries = 3;
bool done = false;
do
{
  try { YourFunction(); done = true; }
  catch { retries--; }
while (!done && retries > 0);

if (!done)
    ShowError();
```

Answer (score 3):

This snippet of code I used in some projects tries an action multiple times. It tries an action the specified amount of times, and if different types of exception occur it aborts immediately.

```
public static void Try(Action action, int tryCount = 3) {
    if (action == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("action");
    if (tryCount <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("tryCount");


    Exception lastException = null;
    bool lastTryFailed = true;
    int timesRemaining = tryCount;
    while (timesRemaining > 0 && lastTryFailed) {
        lastTryFailed = false;
        try {
            action();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if (ex != null && lastException != null &&
                !(
                    ex.GetType() == lastException.GetType() ||
                    ex.GetType().IsSubclassOf(lastException.GetType()) ||
                    lastException.GetType().IsSubclassOf(ex.GetType())
                )
            ) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Different type of exceptions occured during the multiple tried action.", ex);
            }

            // Continue
            lastException = ex;
            lastTryFailed = true;
        }
        timesRemaining--;
    }
    if (lastTryFailed) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Action failed multiple times.", lastException);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple retry mechanism base on a while loop and a counter.

```
const int numTries = 3;
int currentTry = 0;
while (true)
{
   if (DoTheThing())
   {
      break;
   }
   currentTry++
   if (currentTry == numTries)
   {
      //throw or report error
      break;
   }
}
```